# Calling colorbox from a dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu, colorbox

I'm trying to implement calling colorbox items from a dropdown menu. Using this example, http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/, how could I simply call these links from a drop down menu? It seems to work fine in every browser except IE without any additional scripting. I'm sure it's going to be simple fix for anyone with true coding skills. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: maybe show your current code? or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ry9dF/1/

Comment: Have you tried anythign?  The jsfiddle you posted is just the straight up code from the colorbox example page, with no apparent attempt solve your problem.  Have you read the instructions?  You have to at least show some effort - this isn't a "do my work for me" kinda place...

Comment: I really thought it would be a simple event handler that I was missing. ie: <select name="specSelect" size="1" onLoad="function()"> Because the code was straight from the colorbox page, I thought it might be easy solution for you professional coders. (I'm a designer who was thrown code to use and not a strong coder.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something similar after a quick google search

I can't say whether or not this works, but why don't you give it a shot working this code into your jsfiddle, and I'll see if I can help you debug any issues that arise.

from: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/colorbox/OM85IPMoyP4

```
<select name="howheard" id="howheard" class="validate[required]"> 
  <option value="http://example1.com">Example 1</option> 
  <option value="http://example2.com">Example 2</option> 
  <option value="http://example3.com">Example 3</option> 
</select>
```

**EDIT: updadate colorbox() init:**

```
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#howheard").change(function () { 
          var thisHref = $(this).val();
          $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: thisHref}); 
      }); 
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This solution does work but only returns a single URL from the list. I would need to pull a value from the selected option's href tag. I tried using $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: function(){ var url = $(this).attr('href');});  But that didn't work either.

Comment: Looks like you have some extraaneous code there.  Try `... href: $(this).attr('href')});`

Comment: I just gave it an update...  If this helps, please be sure to give it an upvote and/or checkmark ;-)

Comment: It does trigger the event but doesn't pull in the URL. Bounces to the 404 page. makes me think that it's not getting the thisHref as a value.

Comment: Still not returning a value.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I had some malformed code - check it now.  [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8rfQ/1/) shows that it should return a value...

Comment: Well, that fixes it in IE & runs in opera but now firefox & chrome get the 404 errors. (And I was extremely excited there for a moment!)

Comment: Got it!! I doubled the href & the value tags in the menue & they work in all the browsers. It may not be the prettiest fix, but I think that's got it!

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help, Zach. I'll hit the points & Checkmark in just a minute. Thanks again!